# Question about convergence of complex intergration

Tags: complex-analysis

While studying the Lemma(The Lemma is often called [Bombieri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrico_Bombieri) Lemma, I do not know accurately about the name... )

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $\phi$ be a
> subharmonic on $\Omega$ (but,  $\phi \not\equiv  0)$  Take any $z_{0}
>  \in \Omega$ and $a>0$. Then there exists a holomorphic function $h \in
>  \mathcal{O}(\Omega)$ such that $h(z_0)=1$ and  $\int_{\mathbb{C}}
>  \frac{|h|^{2}e^{-\phi}}{(1+|z|^2)^{a+1}}dz <\infty$

My question is not the concrete proof, but the condition given the following Lemma. According to the lecturer, **the constant $a$ cannot be zero**. But I cannot understand the detailed reason why that condition must hold.

The reason is here : suppose $a \equiv 0$ and then take $\Omega = \mathbb{C}, \phi \equiv 0$. If $ h \in \mathcal{O}(\Omega)$ Then,

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\int_{\mathbb{C}}
 \frac{|h|^{2}}{1+|z|^2}dz<\infty$

but, it only holds when $h \equiv 0$....(★). and (★) contradits to the assupmtion $h(z_0)=1$.

But, **my question is why (★) must hold**. By my guesswork, Suppose $h$ is not a zero constant function. When considering polar coordination, ($z=re^{i\theta}$), the following integral is written as

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+(re^{i \theta})^2} h^2(re^{i \theta}) r dr d \theta   $

When observing the radius part,

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r}{1+(re^{i \theta})^2} h^2(re^{i \theta})  dr ...... (1)  $

since $r$ goes to $\infty$, and acutally the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r}{1+(re^{i\theta})^2}dr$ [diverges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%7B0%7D%5E%7Binf%7D%20r%2F%281%2B%28re%5E%7Bi%20%5Ctheta%7D%29%5E2%29%20dr), I expect that  $(1)$ blow up, however because $h^2$ is an arbitray (nonzero constant) the homlorphic function, I would not dare to assure that $(1)$ blow up. (In other words, I think that a holomorhpic function $h$ that makes $(1)$ converge might exist.)

**Note**. I think that the integral notation that is written here is not pretty. (it should type longer integral, but I do not find how to lengthen the notation...)

Comment: The only bounded holomorphic functions on $\Bbb{C}$ are constants. Anything else will be unbounded in at least one direction.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Your claim is not correct: there exist holomorphic functions which are bounded on every line (see "Entire Functions That Tend to Zero on Every Line" by Armitage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $h(z)=\sum a_kz^k$ is entire, by orthogonality and uniform convergence on compacts (and assuming from the context of the OP that $dz$ means $dA$) we have:

$\int_{|z| \le R}\frac{|h|^{2}}{(1+|z|^2)^c}dA=2\pi\sum_{k \ge 0} (|a_k|^2\int_0^R\frac{R^{2k+1}}{(1+|R|^2)^c}dR)$

(edit later per comment - note that $|h(z)|^2=h(z)\overline{h(z)}=(\sum a_kr^ke^{ikt})(\sum \bar a_mr^me^{-imt})=\sum_{k,m \ge 0}a_k\bar a_m r^{k+m}e^{it(k-m)}$ and when integrating term by term in $t$ only the diagonal terms which are $|a_k|^2r^{2k}$ survive to give the $2\pi$ factor, all the rest being zero by orthogonality)

In particular, for $c=1$ each integral is divergent to $\infty$ so all $a_k$ must be $0$ for the integral to converge.

For $c >1$ one has polynomials of low enough degree (eg $1< c \le 2$ allows for constants, $2 <c \le 3$ allows for linear polynomials etc) that give a convergent integral but not a transcendental entire function

Comment: The answer is better! However, when following your calculation in person, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |a_k|^2 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{R}  \frac{r^{2k}}{1+|r|^2} e^{2k i \theta}  r dr d \theta  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |a_k|^2  \int_{0}^{R}  \frac{r^{2k+1}}{1+|r|^2} dr \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{2k i \theta} d \theta $. However, $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{2k i \theta} d \theta = 0$, not $2\pi$. (Obviously, this is a strange result). I am sorry for requiring calculation, but even though I follow your calculation, I cannot yield $2\pi$.

Comment: see the edit for the explicit computaion - the main point is that $|h|^2=h\bar h$ gives terms $e^{it(k-m)}$